# como leer nodos de un Xml especificos en C#

Tags: c#, xml

Hola estoy creando una app en c#
donde cargo un xml (el siguiente):

```
    <UniversalShipment xmlns="http://www.g3.com/Schemas/Universal/2011/11" version="1.1">
      <Shipment>
         <DataContext>
          <DataSourceCollection>
            <DataSource>
              <Type>Shipment</Type>
              <Key>123</Key>
              <Date>2019-12-11</Date>
            </DataSource>
          </DataSourceCollection>
          <Company>
            <Code>NTL</Code>
            <Country>
              <Code>MX</Code>
              <Name>Mexico</Name>
            </Country>
            <Name>testtt SA DE CV</Name>
          </Company>
<FinalDestination>
        <Code>NTLC</Code>
        <Country>
          <Code>MX</Code>
          <Name>Mexico</Name>
        </Country>
        <Name>bunker</Name>
      </FinalDestination>

      <Provider>
        <Code>TST</Code>
        <Country>
          <Code>US</Code>
          <Name>United States</Name>
        </Country>
        <Name>TEST SA DE CV</Name>
      </Provider>
    </DataContext>
      </Shipment>
    </UniversalShipment>
```

tengo problemas al recorrer y obtener la informacion de este nodo.

quiero obtener la info de los nodos de "company" que seria 
code y name

pero como le puedo hacer para obtener los datos del nodo de "Country" 
code y name porque se confunde y me manda informacion de otro no que yo no requiero.

uso lo siguiente:

```
XmlNodeList nodoocompany = midocxml.GetElementsByTagName("Company");

        foreach (XmlElement nodocompany in nodoocompany)
        {

            foreach (XmlElement nodocompanycode in nodocompany.GetElementsByTagName("Code"))
                textBox4.Text = nodocompanycode.InnerText.ToString();


            foreach (XmlElement nodocompanyname in nodocompany.GetElementsByTagName("Name"))
                textBox7.Text = nodocompanyname.InnerText.ToString();

        }
```

cuando ejecuto mi codigo ,en code deberia obtener "NTL"  pero me arroja "MX"

Comment: tienes que acceder al elemento directamente sin hacer foreach

Comment: de esta forma?
XmlNode nodef = midocxml.SelectSingleNode("Company/Code");
            textBox5.Text = nodef.InnerText;

Comment: error mio, si tienes que recorrer pero el primer elemento, checa la respuesta que puse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haciendo uso de `System.Xml.Linq`es mucho más fácil trabajar con este tipo de consultas y no es necesaria "tanta" iteración. Te pongo el ejemplo:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var xml = @"<UniversalShipment><Shipment><DataContext><DataSourceCollection><DataSource><Type>Shipment</Type><Key>123</Key><Date>2019-12-11</Date></DataSource></DataSourceCollection><Company><Code>NTL</Code><Country><Code>MX</Code><Name>Mexico</Name></Country><Name>testtt SA DE CV</Name></Company><FinalDestination><Code>NTLC</Code><Country><Code>MX</Code><Name>Mexico</Name></Country><Name>bunker</Name></FinalDestination><Provider><Code>TST</Code><Country><Code>US</Code><Name>United States</Name></Country><Name>TEST SA DE CV</Name></Provider></DataContext></Shipment></UniversalShipment>";

        var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);     
        var company = doc.Root.Element("Shipment").Element("DataContext").Element("Company");
        var companyCountry = company.Element("Country");

        var dto = new {
            Code = company.Element("Code").Value,
            Country = new {
                Code =  companyCountry.Element("Code").Value,
                Name = companyCountry.Element("Name").Value
            }       
        };                  
        Console.WriteLine($"Company code: {dto.Code} - Country: Code {dto.Country.Code} -> Name {dto.Country.Name}");
    }
}
```

Puedes ver el ejemplo en ejecución aqui: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7o2uKw

Para simplificar el ejemplo, le quité el NS al XML, es posible que debas hacer algunos ajustes para que te funcione, pero para el caso práctico, creo que funciona.

Comment: ya lo acomde con el NS, y si me funciona bien,ademas incorpore el load del xml,gracias.

Comment: Si te fue de utilida, no olvides marcarla como respuesta para que le sirva también a otros usuarios. :P